# How do I create a solid black background in Premiere?

Tags: premiere

I want to create a solid color "video" segment in my overall video. In iMovie I can add it by [importing a background](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/26353/how-to-choose-a-custom-solid-background-color-in-imovie). I don't see any such feature in Premiere Pro.

How do I add a black (or other color) solid color background to my timeline?

Answer (score 2):

1. In the workspaces panel, right-click the background and choose New Item > Color Matte...
2. You can then select any color you want.

See [Easily Create a Solid Color Background in Premier Pro 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpCMxcRq24o) for more details.

Comment: From the same menu, there is also the option of "Black Video" which does the job instantly.